# How do I make Install4j sign everything?

Tags: macos, code-signing, install4j

How do I change what files are signed by install4j's codesigning on Mac OS X?

Specifically, none of my application's files (including its jar file) are signed.  This defeats the purpose of code signing entirely.  So, I would like to fix this.

I would also like to do the same on Windows, but it's possible that this is already handled correctly (I have not yet checked).

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of signing not that everything that can be signed in any way is actually signed.

**Windows** reduces UAC dialogs and shows them with a different warning level if executables are signed. Each launcher that requests elevated privileges has to be signed so that includes the installer, the uninstaller and possibly your launchers.

**Mac OS X** has a "gatekeeper" that checks if an application bundle that was downloaded from the internet is signed. If not, it will not allow you to run it directly. That's why the installer application bundle has to be signed. Gatekeeper is not concerned with any application bundles that are installed by the installer, so they are not signed by default. This is mostly a good thing, since otherwise you would not be able to modify the Info.plist files of your launchers after the installation.

If you use entitlements for gaining access to specific features on Mac OS X your launchers need to be signed as well. You can specify an entitlements file on the "Executable info->Mac OS X options" step of the launcher wizard, and select "Sign installed launchers" on the "Installer options" step of the Mac OS X media file wizard.

install4j is not concerned with signing JAR files. If you need this feature for some reason, you have to do this in your build process.

Comment: OS X Signing actually has another function: to control access to the system keychain.  If you use a signed app to store a password, only signed versions of that app will be able to access that password. This is a valuable security measure, but it's moot if the jar file is not included in the signature.

Comment: OK, I  did not know that. In that case you have to select the sign all launchers option in the media wizard.

Comment: Unfortunately, "sign all launchers" is insufficient.  It only signs the launcher, not the jar file.

Comment: You can sign the JAR files with jarsigner as part of your build process.

Comment: I think that jarsigner's signature won't work for OS X's Gatekeeper.  That is, Gatekeeper does not check that the JAR file is signed at all -- let alone by the same Developer ID as the application.

Comment: But Gatekeeper does not check the signature of jar files, only of application bundles.

Comment: It may well be that current versions of Gatekeepr only checks applications -- but this implies that you can include arbitrary files in the signature.  http://www.erickdransch.com/blog/2012/02/signing-mac-builds/  I wish to do this in case Gatekeeper ever actually decides to work.

Comment: It would also be good if it were possible to upgrade apps while keeping their identity constant (see http://fetchsoftworks.com/fetch/blog/gatekeeper-vs-leopard-an-ongoing-tale for the necessary designated requirements)

Answer (score 0):

@Ingo, it is also true that launcher signing is required for certain restricted functions an application may need (e.g. opening a network socket).  I also think I should mention the  "Sign installed launchers" on the "Installer options" step is not available on the "Mac OS X single bundle" media type, so users will need to choose another media type if they require launching signing.

This wasn't clear in the documentation, so hopefully this comment can save someone some time.