# How to make install4j sign the Mac launcher app?

Tags: java, macos, install4j

Using install4j 7.0.3 (latest version) to generate dmg, installer, and launcher, I can validate that the dmg and the installer app are being signed with my Mac Developer ID, but the launcher app (the app that gets installed in the /Applications folder) does not get signed. I can't find an option to turn this on in install4j, as indicated in an answer to this question in a previous version of install4j back in 2013 [How do I make Install4j sign everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224625/how-do-i-make-install4j-sign-everything/17230832#17230832)).

After downloading and installing my app, testing its signature give the following result:

```
$ codesign -dv /Applications/MyApp.app
/Applications/MyApp.app: code object is not signed at all
```

How do I make install4j sign the launcher app that it generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single bundle installer media file type produces a signed installer, but the contents of the installation depend on numerous factors in the installer, so the installed bundle cannot be signed.

You can either use the single bundle archive media file type or the folder installer media type instead if you need signed launcher bundles.